# How do I find the creator of a Perforce changelist?

Tags: perforce

I have two Perforce users A and B. A creates a numbered changelist 4711 and assigns this changelist to B with the command:

```
p4 change -U B 4711
```

User B can now verify that he owns changelist 4711 by calling:

```
p4 describe -s 4711
```

Is there any way for user B to find out that this changelist was created by A?

Regards

Lars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not via any Perforce client commands, no.  This information isn't versioned in the metadata or the spec depot.  Options for the admin include:

1. Putting a trigger in place that will record this information somewhere.
2. Searching the journal for modifications to the `@db.change@` record.
3. Searching the log file for uses of the `p4 change -U` command.